# Where does SecKeyGeneratePair store keypair?

Tags: ios, keychain, key-pair

I'm trying to use SecKeyGeneratePair, and I've set the attribute to kSecAttrTokenIDSecureEnclave as well as left it blank. According to https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/ksecattrtokenid if kSecAttrTokenID isn't set, the item should be stored in the normal keychain DB. However, regardless of whether I set it, the keychain-2.db file size doesn't change. I'm however able to use SecKeyRawSign() with the generated private key without any errors. Where then is the private key stored?

Answer (score 0):

If you set kSecAttrTokenIDSecureEnclave, then the real private key is stored somewhere in the secure enclave, and the private key that is returned to you is just referencing the real private key in the secure enclave. However, as far as using the key is concerned, it doesn't make any difference. You use the SecKey that you received in exactly the same way.

If you want to use the same keypair on consecutive runs of your application, as you most likely want, you must store the private key that you received in the key chain and retrieve it from the keychain when the app launches again, whether you use this token or not. If you don't, then you have no SecKey, so the private key is still in the secure enclave somehow, but you lost any way to access it.

Look at it like this: Normally, a SecKey is a box with a door key or a car key inside. But using kSecAttrTokenIDSecureEnclave, the SecKey is a box with a piece of paper inside that tells where the real key is in the secure enclave. iOS is clever enough to handle both kinds of boxes identically. However, you need to store each kind of box in the keychain yourself. If you don't take care of the box, it's gone when your app relaunches.